# How can I restore the on press button behavior on Kivy?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

So, I am trying to make a drawing application using some buttons and canvas using Python and Kivy. The problem is that when I use the on_touch_down function, my buttons stop working. I guess this is caused due to me redefining the method that is used when checking the touch down events. If this is the case, could you please tell me how I can make my buttons work again?

To be more specific, I am using canvas to draw lines (and through them empty rectangles as well). The thing is that when I try to click my buttons, they do not work. In fact, a line is drawn on top of them.

This is my code for my python file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class Touch(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.active_tool = "Line"
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 1, mode="rgba")
            self.lines = [Line(points = [0, 0, 0, 0], width = 2)]
            self.rectangles = [Line(points = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], width = 2)]
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.active_tool == "Line":
            self.lines[-1].points = [touch.x, touch.y]
        elif self.active_tool == "Rectangle":
            self.rectangles[-1].points = [touch.x, touch.y]
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.active_tool == "Line":
            self.lines[-1].points = [self.lines[-1].points[0], self.lines[-1].points[1], touch.x, touch.y]
        elif self.active_tool == "Rectangle":
            self.rectangles[-1].points = [self.rectangles[-1].points[0], self.rectangles[-1].points[1], touch.x, self.rectangles[-1].points[1], touch.x, touch.y, self.rectangles[-1].points[0], touch.y, self.rectangles[-1].points[0], self.rectangles[-1].points[1]]
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.active_tool == "Line":
            with self.canvas:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 1, mode="rgba")
                self.lines.append(Line(points = [0, 0, 0, 0], width = 2))
        elif self.active_tool == "Rectangle":
            with self.canvas:
                self.rectangles.append(Line(points = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], width = 2))
class DrawingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Touch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DrawingApp().run()
```

This is my code for my kivy file

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 40, 40
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

<Touch>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    CustButton:
        pos: root.x, root.height - 50
        background_normal: "img/straight_line_icon.png"
        on_press: root.active_tool = "Line"

    CustButton:
        pos: root.x, root.height - 100
        background_normal: "img/rectangle_icon.png"
```

If you need the files, I can upload them to some website like mediafire. But for now, I think it could be bothersome for some people if right away I put a link to mediafire.

Answer (score 0):

The `on_touch` methods affect the dispatching of touch events. If you want touch events to be correctly dispatched, you should call the `super` `on_touch` methods. For example:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.active_tool == "Line":
        self.lines[-1].points = [touch.x, touch.y]
    elif self.active_tool == "Rectangle":
        self.rectangles[-1].points = [touch.x, touch.y]
    return super(Touch, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Similar for the other `touch` methods.